# WordPress Plugin for Facebook to auto post on page

Tags: facebook, wordpress, plugins, facebook-page

I need to configure wordpress plugin "Facebook" to auto post my blog posts on Facebook Official Page which is under my business account. As I know we need App ID and App Secret to configure it out, but we can't create an app under business account.
Any solution to do this?